# Django Filter Queryset is not the same when slice

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I have a wired question,.. Can anyone tell me why there is a different here.
I just want the top 4 most clicked products logged in the Track model, and i works .. but what I don't get is why there is at diff when using [:4] and not.

```
Product.objects.annotate(c=Count("track")).filter(~Q(track__useragent__icontains="bot")).order_by("-c")[:4]
Product.objects.annotate(c=Count("track")).filter(~Q(track__useragent__icontains="bot")).order_by("-c")
```

I think that the 4 first items in the list should be the same with or without the [:4] slicing, but it is not!

Comment: the first one sets a limit of 4 results and the second one doesn't. What's confusing you here?

Comment: That the first 4 is not the same... Is that making sense?

Comment: Oh you edited the question, yeah now it's a lot clearer. Yes your assumption is correct. It's quite odd, normally the first four should indeed be the same. How do you know they are not the same? How did you compare them?

Comment: Did you compare the SQL queries to see what is actually queried?